# MongoDB Node.js native driver silently swallows `bulkWrite` exception

Tags: node.js, mongodb

The script below has a bug in the mongo bulkWrite op syntax: `$setOnInsert: { count:0 },` is unnecessary and thus mongo throws an exception: "Cannot update 'count' and 'count' at the same time".

The problem is, the node.js driver doesn't seem to catch it. This script logs "Success!" to the console.

```
(async () => {

  let db = await require('mongodb').MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/myNewDb');

  let mongoOps = [{
    updateOne: {
      filter: { foo: "bar" },
      update: {
        $setOnInsert: { count:0 },
        $inc: { count:1 },
      },
      upsert: true,
    }
  }];

  try {
    await db.collection("myNewCollection").bulkWrite(mongoOps);
    console.log("Success!");
  } catch(e) {
    console.log("Failed:");
    console.log(e);
  }

})();
```

Examining `db.system.profile.find({})` with `db.setProfileLevel(2)` we can see the exception:

```
{
    "op" : "update",
    "ns" : "myNewDb.myNewCollection",
    "query" : {
        "foo" : "bar"
    },
    "updateobj" : {
        "$setOnInsert" : {
            "count" : 0
        },
        "$inc" : {
            "count" : 1
        }
    },
    "keyUpdates" : 0,
    "writeConflicts" : 0,
    "numYield" : 0,
    "locks" : {
        "Global" : {
            "acquireCount" : {
                "r" : NumberLong(1),
                "w" : NumberLong(1)
            }
        },
        "Database" : {
            "acquireCount" : {
                "w" : NumberLong(1)
            }
        },
        "Collection" : {
            "acquireCount" : {
                "w" : NumberLong(1)
            }
        }
    },
    "exception" : "Cannot update 'count' and 'count' at the same time",
    "exceptionCode" : 16836,
    "millis" : 0,
    "execStats" : {},
    "ts" : ISODate("2017-10-12T01:57:03.008Z"),
    "client" : "127.0.0.1",
    "allUsers" : [],
    "user" : ""
}
```

Why is the driver swallowing errors like this? I definitely seems like a bug, but I figured I'd ask here first just to be sure.

Comment: Interesting. The error is actually present in the response, but an exception is not being thrown. Also the response status is `ok: 1` despite the presence of `writeErrors` That at least gives an indication of where to look in the source. But it's definitely a bug. You could therefore "work around" by examining the length of `writeErrors` in the response. But you really should not have to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as commented, "It's a bug". Specifically the bug is [right here](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/2.2/lib/collection.js#L613-L619):

```
 // Return a Promise
  return new this.s.promiseLibrary(function(resolve, reject) {
    bulkWrite(self, operations, options, function(err, r) {
      if(err && r == null) return reject(err);
      resolve(r);
    });
  });
```

The problem is that the "response" ( or `r` ) in the callback which is being wrapped in a `Promise` is not actually `null`, and therefore despite the error being present the condition is therefore not `true` and `reject(err)` is not being called, but rather the `resolve(r)` is being sent and hence this is not considered an exception.

Correcting would need some triage, but you can either 'work around' as mentioned by inspecting the `writeErrors` property in the response from the current `bulkWrite()` implementation or consider one of the other alternatives as:

#### Using the Bulk API methods directly:

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
      uri  = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/myNewDb';

(async () => {

  let db;

  try {

    db = await MongoClient.connect(uri);

    let bulk = db.collection('myNewCollection').initializeOrderedBulkOp();

    bulk.find({ foo: 'bar' }).upsert().updateOne({
      $setOnInsert: { count: 0 },
      $inc: { count: 0 }
    });

    let result = await bulk.execute();
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result,undefined,2));

  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
  } finally {
    db.close();
  }

})();
```

Perfectly fine but of course has the issue of not naturally regressing on server implementations without Bulk API support to using the legacy API methods instead.

#### Wrapping the Promise Manually

```
(async () => {

  let db = await require('mongodb').MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/myNewDb');

  let mongoOps = [{
    updateOne: {
      filter: { foo: "bar" },
      update: {
        $setOnInsert: { count:0 },
        $inc: { count:1 },
      },
      upsert: true,
    }
  }];

  try {
    let result = await new Promise((resolve,reject) => {

      db.collection("myNewCollection").bulkWrite(mongoOps, (err,r) => {
        if (err) reject(err);
        resolve(r);
      });
    });
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result,undefined,2));
    console.log("Success!");
  } catch(e) {
    console.log("Failed:");
    console.log(e);
  }

})();
```

As noted the problem lies within the implementation of how `bulkWrite()` is returning as a `Promise`. So instead you can code with the `callback()` form and do your own `Promise` wrapping in order to act how you expect it to.

Again as noted, needs a JIRA issue and Triage to which is the correct way to handle the exceptions. But hopefully gets resolved soon. In the meantime, pick an approach from above.

Comment: Thanks, Neil! Yep, I'm working around by inspecting the result object at the moment. I'll assume that you're a maintainer or that you're reporting this since that seems to come across in your answer, but let me know if you'd like me to post a bug report somewhere and I'll hop right to it.

Comment: @JoeRocc Actually already posted.[NODE-1158](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/NODE-1158) is added for tracking.

Comment: Fixed as of 3.0.0