# Function insertMany() unordered: proper way to get both the errors and the result?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

It seems that MongoDB `insertMany()` function with ordered option set to false can insert documents more efficiently than with ordered option set to true. And it can continue inserting documents even if several documents fail to insert.

But I found that there is no clean way to get both each failed document's error and overall command result.

(BTW, I'm using Node.js driver API 2.2. I will refer the driver's source code from now on: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/lib_collection.js.html)

First, If Promise is used, there is no way to get both the errors and the result. On source code line 540, `insertMany()` returns either the error or the result - not both, while `bulkWrite()` callback returns both on source code line 703.

Second, If callback is used, things get worse. When `bulkWrite()` calls the callback with both the error and the result, `insertMany()` calls the callback with both the error and the result, but the result is the BulkWrite's result, not the properly converted one to InsertManyResults. Please see the source code line 535. I think this is a bug.

And even for `bulkWrite()`, when the number of the errors is 1, it does not convert the result properly to its format. Please see the source code line 669. I think this is also a bug.

Now I think that the Node.js driver is simply not prepared to handle the case.

For now, it seems that there is no way to get both the errors and results properly.

Am I right?

**UPDATE**

I've run a test code which is based on Neil Lunn's answer. Since my
Node.js(4.4.5) does not understand async/await, I had to rewrite the test code with explicit Promises.

The test code is as follows:

```
function doTest()
{
    var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
    var testData = [ 1,2,2,3,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 ];
    var db;

    return MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1/test')
    .then(function (_db)
    {
        db = _db;
        return db.createCollection('test');
    })
    .then(function ()
    {
        return db.collection('test').deleteMany({})
        .then(function ()
        {
            return db.collection('test').insertMany(
                testData.map(function (_id)
                {
                    return { _id: _id };
                }),
                { ordered: false })
            .then(function (result)
            {
                console.log('Promise: result', result);
            }, function (err)
            {
                console.log('Promise: error', err);
            });
        })
        .then(function ()
        {
            return db.collection('test').deleteMany({});
        })
        .then(function ()
        {
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject)
            {
                return db.collection('test').insertMany(
                    testData.map(function (_id)
                    {
                        return { _id: _id };
                    }),
                    { ordered: false },
                    function (err, result)
                {
                    console.log('callback: error', err);
                    console.log('callback: result', result);
                    console.log('callback: result.hasWriteErrors', result.hasWriteErrors());
                    console.log('callback: result.getWriteErrors',
                        JSON.stringify(result.getWriteErrors(), null, 2));
                    resolve();
                });
            });
        });
    })
    .catch(function (err)
    {
        console.log('catch', err);
    })
    .then(function ()
    {
        db.close();
    });
}
doTest();
```

And here is the result:

```
Promise: error { [MongoError: write operation failed]
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'write operation failed',
  driver: true,
  code: 11000,
  writeErrors: 
   [ { code: [Getter],
       index: [Getter],
       errmsg: [Getter],
       getOperation: [Function],
       toJSON: [Function],
       toString: [Function] },
     { code: [Getter],
       index: [Getter],
       errmsg: [Getter],
       getOperation: [Function],
       toJSON: [Function],
       toString: [Function] } ] }
callback: error { [MongoError: write operation failed]
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'write operation failed',
  driver: true,
  code: 11000,
  writeErrors: 
   [ { code: [Getter],
       index: [Getter],
       errmsg: [Getter],
       getOperation: [Function],
       toJSON: [Function],
       toString: [Function] },
     { code: [Getter],
       index: [Getter],
       errmsg: [Getter],
       getOperation: [Function],
       toJSON: [Function],
       toString: [Function] } ] }
callback: result { ok: [Getter],
  nInserted: [Getter],
  nUpserted: [Getter],
  nMatched: [Getter],
  nModified: [Getter],
  nRemoved: [Getter],
  getInsertedIds: [Function],
  getUpsertedIds: [Function],
  getUpsertedIdAt: [Function],
  getRawResponse: [Function],
  hasWriteErrors: [Function],
  getWriteErrorCount: [Function],
  getWriteErrorAt: [Function],
  getWriteErrors: [Function],
  getLastOp: [Function],
  getWriteConcernError: [Function],
  toJSON: [Function],
  toString: [Function],
  isOk: [Function],
  insertedCount: 9,
  matchedCount: 0,
  modifiedCount: 0,
  deletedCount: 0,
  upsertedCount: 0,
  upsertedIds: {},
  insertedIds: 
   { '0': 1,
     '1': 2,
     '2': 2,
     '3': 3,
     '4': 3,
     '5': 4,
     '6': 5,
     '7': 6,
     '8': 7,
     '9': 8,
     '10': 9 },
  n: 9 }
callback: result.hasWriteErrors true
callback: result.getWriteErrors [
  {
    "code": 11000,
    "index": 2,
    "errmsg": "E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.test index: _id_ dup key: { : 2 }",
    "op": {
      "_id": 2
    }
  },
  {
    "code": 11000,
    "index": 4,
    "errmsg": "E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.test index: _id_ dup key: { : 3 }",
    "op": {
      "_id": 3
    }
  }
]
```

Now, I've run the code again, with the testData variable modified as follows:

```
var testData = [ 1,2,3,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 ];
```

In this case, the number of errors will be 1, instead of 2, since the duplicate '2' is removed.

And here is the result:

```
Promise: error { [MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.test index: _id_ dup key: { : 3 }]
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.test index: _id_ dup key: { : 3 }',
  driver: true,
  code: 11000,
  index: 3,
  errmsg: 'E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.test index: _id_ dup key: { : 3 }',
  getOperation: [Function],
  toJSON: [Function],
  toString: [Function] }
callback: error { [MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.test index: _id_ dup key: { : 3 }]
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.test index: _id_ dup key: { : 3 }',
  driver: true,
  code: 11000,
  index: 3,
  errmsg: 'E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.test index: _id_ dup key: { : 3 }',
  getOperation: [Function],
  toJSON: [Function],
  toString: [Function] }
callback: result { ok: [Getter],
  nInserted: [Getter],
  nUpserted: [Getter],
  nMatched: [Getter],
  nModified: [Getter],
  nRemoved: [Getter],
  getInsertedIds: [Function],
  getUpsertedIds: [Function],
  getUpsertedIdAt: [Function],
  getRawResponse: [Function],
  hasWriteErrors: [Function],
  getWriteErrorCount: [Function],
  getWriteErrorAt: [Function],
  getWriteErrors: [Function],
  getLastOp: [Function],
  getWriteConcernError: [Function],
  toJSON: [Function],
  toString: [Function],
  isOk: [Function] }
callback: result.hasWriteErrors true
callback: result.getWriteErrors [
  {
    "code": 11000,
    "index": 3,
    "errmsg": "E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.test index: _id_ dup key: { : 3 }",
    "op": {
      "_id": 3
    }
  }
]
```

The format of error and result is fairly different from the first run.

- the error has no writeErrors field.
- the result has no 'converted' fields. (insertedCount, matchedCount, etc.) This is a 'bug' on the driver source code line 669 as I've told above.

And in both test runs, the types of the result argument are NOT `Collection~insertWriteOpResult`. The first one is `Collection~bulkWriteOpCallback`, and the second one is more internal one. So, the API document is wrong in this case. This is caused by the 'bugs' on line 535 and 669 as I've told above.

So, even if the result can be used (indeed, the result has `hasWriteErrors()` and `getWriteErrors()` as Neil Lunn told), since this behavior is not documented, I suspect that it can be changed on later versions without notice, and my code will break.

Comment: [NODE-1158](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/NODE-1158) which does have links to recent commits in the 3.x branch related to this. There are workarounds to this as mentioned on [MongoDB Node.js native driver silently swallows `bulkWrite` exception](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46700461/2313887). Perhaps you should show the code you have a problem with implementing so you can be pointed to the correct way to handle it if you don't understand what the answer there describes.

Comment: I should note that as commented on several places there, your statement that "you cannot get both" is intrinsically incorrect. The core issue addressed in the refactor for the new branch is that the underlying "Bulk" API calls actually **do** return "both" the error as well a `BulkWriteResult` which contains the error information in the "callback". The issue corrects this behavior to remove the "result" and make a `BulkWriteError` response only. Which for "unordered" includes the "success" information, as well as the array of "errors".

Comment: @NeilLunn Actually I didn't write any code yet. It's the first time for me to write a code to use any bulk-write API of MongoDB JavaScript driver. I've read the document (http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#insertMany) and found the document does not mention the case properly. So I began to explore the source code, and found the source code's current state. I don't want to write any code for this state.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is really only with how a "Promise" resolves and how the error information is passed, but of course the real core issue is that there **is** in fact a return of "both" the error and result information when any "Bulk" operation is set to `{ ordered: false  }`. This is being addressed in the driver for the 3.x release as noted on [NODE-1158](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/NODE-1158) which also contains links to the commits in the future branch that fix the issue.

The "workaround" for this is to be aware that "both" the result an error information are present in the `BulkWriteResult` object returned as the result in the "callback" invocation of any such methods ( note `insertMany()` and even `bulkWrite()` actually wrap an underlying [Bulk API Implementation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk/) ).

To demonstrate with a listing:

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

const uri = 'mongodb://localhost/test';
const testData = [1,2,3,3,4,5,6,6,7,8,9];

(async function() {

  let db;

  try {

    db = await MongoClient.connect(uri);

    await db.collection('test').remove();

    // Expect an error here - but it's just the errors
    try {
      let result = await db.collection('test').insertMany(
        testData.map( _id => ({ _id }) ),
        { "ordered": false }
      );
      console.log(result);   // never gets here
    } catch(e) {
      console.dir(e);
      console.log(JSON.stringify(e.writeErrors,undefined,2));
    }

    await db.collection('test').remove();
    // Wrapped callback so we see what happens

    try {
      let result = await new Promise((resolve,reject) => 
        db.collection('test').insertMany(
          testData.map( _id => ({ _id }) ),
          { "ordered": false },
          (err,result) => {
            if (err) reject(result);    // Because the errors are here as well
            resolve(result);
          }
        )
      );
      console.log(result);  // Never gets here
    } catch(e) {
      console.dir(e);
      console.log(e.hasWriteErrors());
      console.log(JSON.stringify(e.getWriteErrors(),undefined,2));
    }

  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
  } finally {
    db.close();
  }

})();
```

So there are two blocks of code there that attempt to use `insertMany()` with a list of values that are going to produce duplicate key errors for some of the values.

In the first attempt, we use the default `Promise` return which as should be indicated by the implemented code of the driver is simply going to pass the `err` callback result in the method it wraps into it's `reject()` statement. This means we go to the `catch` block here and produce the error information as output:

```
{ MongoError: [object Object]
    at Function.MongoError.create (/home/neillunn/projects/bulkerror/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/error.js:31:11)
    at toError (/home/neillunn/projects/bulkerror/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:139:22)
    at /home/neillunn/projects/bulkerror/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:701:23
    at handleCallback (/home/neillunn/projects/bulkerror/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:120:56)
    at /home/neillunn/projects/bulkerror/node_modules/mongodb/lib/bulk/unordered.js:465:9
    at handleCallback (/home/neillunn/projects/bulkerror/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:120:56)
    at resultHandler (/home/neillunn/projects/bulkerror/node_modules/mongodb/lib/bulk/unordered.js:413:5)
    at /home/neillunn/projects/bulkerror/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:469:18
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'write operation failed',
  driver: true,
  code: 11000,
  writeErrors:
   [ WriteError {
       code: [Getter],
       index: [Getter],
       errmsg: [Getter],
       getOperation: [Function],
       toJSON: [Function],
       toString: [Function] },
     WriteError {
       code: [Getter],
       index: [Getter],
       errmsg: [Getter],
       getOperation: [Function],
       toJSON: [Function],
       toString: [Function] } ] }
[
  {
    "code": 11000,
    "index": 3,
    "errmsg": "E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.test index: _id_ dup key: { : 3 }",
    "op": {
      "_id": 3
    }
  },
  {
    "code": 11000,
    "index": 7,
    "errmsg": "E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.test index: _id_ dup key: { : 6 }",
    "op": {
      "_id": 6
    }
  }
]
```

Note that this is a wrapped `MongoError` and despite the fact we set `{ ordered: false }` there is no "result" information in the response. We can see on detailed inspection of the error information that the list of `WriteError` does have details on each duplicate key error produced.

So there was successful writes for everything in the batch that did not throw an error, but it's not reported in anything obtainable **from the `Promise`**. But this is not true of the underlying method, which is still implemented using a callback.

The second attempt wraps this callback "manually", so we can in fact see the result by altering the behavior and passing the `result` object to `reject` when an `err` is present. This tells us a different story:

```
BulkWriteResult {
  ok: [Getter],
  nInserted: [Getter],
  nUpserted: [Getter],
  nMatched: [Getter],
  nModified: [Getter],
  nRemoved: [Getter],
  getInsertedIds: [Function],
  getUpsertedIds: [Function],
  getUpsertedIdAt: [Function],
  getRawResponse: [Function],
  hasWriteErrors: [Function],
  getWriteErrorCount: [Function],
  getWriteErrorAt: [Function],
  getWriteErrors: [Function],
  getLastOp: [Function],
  getWriteConcernError: [Function],
  toJSON: [Function],
  toString: [Function],
  isOk: [Function],
  insertedCount: 9,
  matchedCount: 0,
  modifiedCount: 0,
  deletedCount: 0,
  upsertedCount: 0,
  upsertedIds: {},
  insertedIds:
   { '0': 1,
     '1': 2,
     '2': 3,
     '3': 3,
     '4': 4,
     '5': 5,
     '6': 6,
     '7': 6,
     '8': 7,
     '9': 8,
     '10': 9 },
  n: 9 }
true
[
  {
    "code": 11000,
    "index": 3,
    "errmsg": "E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.test index: _id_ dup key: { : 3 }",
    "op": {
      "_id": 3
    }
  },
  {
    "code": 11000,
    "index": 7,
    "errmsg": "E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.test index: _id_ dup key: { : 6 }",
    "op": {
      "_id": 6
    }
  }
]
```

Since we did not pass back the `err` we now see the `BulkWriteResult` in the catch block. We know we got there because of the specific code we are running in that block to inspect the result.

The regular result does indeed have some things as the modified or inserted count, as well as the list of `insertedIds`. We can also see from inspection that `hasWriteErrors()` returns `true`, and we can obtain the list of `WriteError` which we have serialized for better viewing.

### Fixed in 3.x

As noted on the linked issue, the actual fix will only be present in the 3.x driver release which will support MongoDB 3.6. The "fix" is essentially done at a "lower level" to **not** return a `BulkWriteResult` at all, but instead make `err` return a `BulkWriteError`.

This actually makes things more consistent with how some other drivers have correctly implemented this already. It's honestly a bit of a "hangover" from traditional "node style" callbacks, where "both" error and response are always returned.

So bringing this into "just an error" makes things more consistent and works as you would generally expect.

As a bit of a side note, the related issue in [MongoDB Node.js native driver silently swallows bulkWrite exception.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46700461/2313887) referenced in the JIRA issue shows the actual `bulkWrite()` method in the implementation ( which is not "directly" what `insertMany()` wraps ) has a slightly different problem in that "no error" actually gets thrown at all, because the code is expecting `result` to be `null` and as described it is not.

So the reverse case is true there where we never get to `catch` for the exception in the default implementation using a `Promise`. However the exact same method of handling is what should be applied, by manually wrapping the callback and sending the `result` through `reject` in preference to `err` when both those are returned as not `null`.

Work around them as described, and preferably move to the new driver as soon as it becomes available. Which should be fairly soon anyway.

Comment: (I've deleted my 2 comments since it's base on my misunderstanding. I will write another later.)

Comment: I've updated my question. In short, even if the result can be used, at least for the current version it's the unintended side effect of the 'bug' in the driver's code, so it can't be used without risking breaking the code between the driver versions (even the minor ones).

Comment: So for now, I think I will stick to insertOne() loop and live with the performance penalty. (I don't know the amount of the penalty)

Comment: @zeodtr I really don't get how you cannot understand this. It's explained in a fair bit of detail. I've pointed out it's a "legacy" of handling node style callbacks which provide both error and result. And there is no difference between your changed number of duplicates, other than that there is "one" error in the array. That's it. Bottom line is I and many others have production code using this ( with callbacks, because I saw no advantage in promises at the time ) for years. Works fine when you know what to look for. Which is what you are being told here.

Comment: @zeodtr You seem to be hung up on "I found a bug!". So hate to burst your bubble but you did not find it. The issue is logged, everyone is aware of it and it's been addressed in the release where it's going to be changed in how it behaves. Just as also explained in the answer. So what else you expect I really don't know.

Comment: Sorry if I made you upset. But my thought is simple: It is not usable for now, since the driver code's actual behavior is different from the documentation, and largely undocumented. I don't care it is called a bug or legacy or whatever. (So I quoted it - 'bug'). I will wait for the next version. And maybe you've read my first update - I've updated the question again, I wish the second update is clearer to you.

Comment: @zeodtr All I'm asking you is "what is not answered?" Your question asks "how to get both errors and result?" that's what you are being shown. So in what way do you think this does not answer the question? I don't see any "question" in the update at all. And if you have something else to ask then you [Ask a new Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). So not upset, but just stunned and confused. Do you want help or not? If you want help then say what you don't yet understand.

Comment: Your answer is helpful, (and thank you for that) but unfortunately not possible to be applied to the production code, since it seems to be based on the unintended side effects of the driver source code. It would be great if your answer is backed officially by MongoDB team and the document is updated accordingly. (if so, I think the document will get somewhat messy...)

Comment: @zeodtr You do realize you got pointed to a JIRA issue which contains the links to the source commit that actually addresses the underlying issue within the answer. And there is also this https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/3.0.0/CHANGES_3.0.0.md#bulkwriteresult--bulkwriteerror. It does not get more "official" than in the repository already.

Comment: Would you mind if the following paragraph (or a better one if possible) is added to the beginning of the answer? [There is no 'proper' way, since there is no properly documented way to do it for version 2.2. But you can apply the following workaround if you are in a hurry, or wait for the next version (3.0) which has more consistent way to do it (explained below).]. Then I can accept this answer. (Sorry for this, but I want to emphasize the version 2.2's somewhat inconsistent state and so give users some warning.)

Comment: @zeodtr Considering that I disagree with the opinion then I do mind. What I am showing here is how to correctly handle how the driver is presently implemented. I have linked to the relevant JIRA issues in response and that is enough. You are free to have whatever opinion you wish, but as I have repeatedly stated and demonstrated, your presumptions are not factual or correct.