# insertMany Handle Duplicate Errors

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to bulk insert (array of object) into my document but I want to prevent duplicate records, couldn't find a way to do it with insertMany.

```
const Song = require('../models/song');
Song.insertMany([{id:1, name:"something"},{id:2, name:"something else"])
    .then((result) => {
      res.json({
        result
      })
    })
```

Above code worked but if the record is the same it will still get inserted.

Comment: @chade_ I did tried, tried bout an hour at least, updated my question with code.

Comment: There actually is a distinct difference here because `_id` is the actual primary key, and whilst mongoose allows you to "get away with" using `id` as an "alias" to this in most cases, this is not the case for `insertMany()`. With your schema actually lacking such a property, this will be "discarded" and thus it does not matter if you supply the same value or not since it never writes. But there is actually a much bigger picture to this than that simple error.

Comment: In Python, mongo throws an error if there are (some) duplicates but it actually does the operation for the remaining documents (when ordered=False is passed). This is very counterintuitive. The solution is to insert documents inside a try and inspect the Exceptions for monitoring.

Answer (score 13):

Well in actual fact, MongoDB by "default" will not create duplicate data where there is a "unique key" involved, of which `_id` ( aliased by mongoose as `id`, but ignored by `insertMany()` so you need to be careful ), but there is a much larger story to this that you **really need to be aware of**.

The basic problem here is that both the "mongoose" implementation of `insertMany()` as well as the underlying driver are currently are bit "borked" to put it mildly. That being there is a bit of an inconsistency in how the driver passes the error response in "Bulk" operations and this is actually compounded by "mongoose" not really "looking in the right place" for the actual error information.

The "quick" part you are missing is the addition of `{ ordered: false }` to the "Bulk" operation of which `.insertMany()` simply wraps a call to. Setting this ensures that the "batch" of requests is actually submitted "completely" and does not stop execution when an error occurs.

But since "mongoose" does not handle this very well ( nor does the driver "consistently" ) we actually need to look for possible "errors" in the "response" rather than the "error" result of the underlying callback.

As a demonstration:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose'),
      Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.set('debug',true);

const uri = 'mongodb://localhost/test',
      options = { useMongoClient: true };

const songSchema = new Schema({
  _id: Number,
  name: String
});

const Song = mongoose.model('Song', songSchema);

function log(data) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2))
}

let docs = [
  { _id: 1, name: "something" },
  { _id: 2, name: "something else" },
  { _id: 2, name: "something else entirely" },
  { _id: 3, name: "another thing" }
];

mongoose.connect(uri,options)
  .then( () => Song.remove() )
  .then( () =>
    new Promise((resolve,reject) =>
      Song.collection.insertMany(docs,{ ordered: false },function(err,result) {
        if (result.hasWriteErrors()) {
          // Log something just for the sake of it
          console.log('Has Write Errors:');
          log(result.getWriteErrors());

          // Check to see if something else other than a duplicate key, and throw
          if (result.getWriteErrors().some( error => error.code != 11000 ))
            reject(err);
        }
        resolve(result);    // Otherwise resolve
      })
    )
  )
  .then( results => { log(results); return true; } )
  .then( () => Song.find() )
  .then( songs => { log(songs); mongoose.disconnect() })
  .catch( err => { console.error(err); mongoose.disconnect(); } );
```

Or perhaps a bit nicer since current LTS node.js has `async/await`:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose'),
      Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.set('debug',true);

const uri = 'mongodb://localhost/test',
      options = { useMongoClient: true };

const songSchema = new Schema({
  _id: Number,
  name: String
});

const Song = mongoose.model('Song', songSchema);

function log(data) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2))
}

let docs = [
  { _id: 1, name: "something" },
  { _id: 2, name: "something else" },
  { _id: 2, name: "something else entirely" },
  { _id: 3, name: "another thing" }
];

(async function() {

  try {
    const conn = await mongoose.connect(uri,options);

    await Song.remove();

    let results = await new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
      Song.collection.insertMany(docs,{ ordered: false },function(err,result) {
        if (result.hasWriteErrors()) {
          // Log something just for the sake of it
          console.log('Has Write Errors:');
          log(result.getWriteErrors());

          // Check to see if something else other than a duplicate key, then throw
          if (result.getWriteErrors().some( error => error.code != 11000 ))
            reject(err);
        }
        resolve(result);    // Otherwise resolve

      });
    });

    log(results);

    let songs = await Song.find();
    log(songs);

  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
  } finally {
    mongoose.disconnect();
  }


})()
```

At any rate, you get the same result showing that writes are both continued and that we respectfully "ignore" errors that are related to a "duplicate key" or otherwise known as error code `11000`. The "safe handling" is that we expect such errors and discard them whilst looking for the presence of "other errors" that we might just want to pay attention to. We also see the rest of the code continues and lists all documents actually inserted by executing a subsequent `.find()` call:

```
Mongoose: songs.remove({}, {})
Mongoose: songs.insertMany([ { _id: 1, name: 'something' }, { _id: 2, name: 'something else' }, { _id: 2, name: 'something else entirely' }, { _id: 3, name: 'another thing' } ], { ordered: false })
Has Write Errors:
[
  {
    "code": 11000,
    "index": 2,
    "errmsg": "E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.songs index: _id_ dup key: { : 2 }",
    "op": {
      "_id": 2,
      "name": "something else entirely"
    }
  }
]
{
  "ok": 1,
  "writeErrors": [
    {
      "code": 11000,
      "index": 2,
      "errmsg": "E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.songs index: _id_ dup key: { : 2 }",
      "op": {
        "_id": 2,
        "name": "something else entirely"
      }
    }
  ],
  "writeConcernErrors": [],
  "insertedIds": [
    {
      "index": 0,
      "_id": 1
    },
    {
      "index": 1,
      "_id": 2
    },
    {
      "index": 2,
      "_id": 2
    },
    {
      "index": 3,
      "_id": 3
    }
  ],
  "nInserted": 3,
  "nUpserted": 0,
  "nMatched": 0,
  "nModified": 0,
  "nRemoved": 0,
  "upserted": [],
  "lastOp": {
    "ts": "6485492726828630028",
    "t": 23
  }
}
Mongoose: songs.find({}, { fields: {} })
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "name": "something"
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "name": "something else"
  },
  {
    "_id": 3,
    "name": "another thing"
  }
]
```

So why this process? The reason being that the underlying call actually returns both the `err` and `result` as shown in the callback implementation but there is an inconsistency in what is returned. The main reason to do this is so you actually see the "result", which not only has the result of the successful operation, but also the error message.

Along with the error information is the `nInserted: 3` indicating how many out of the "batch" actually were written. You can pretty much ignore the `insertedIds` here since this particular test involved actually supplying `_id` values. In the event where a different property had the "unique" constraint that caused the error, then the only values here would be those from actual successful writes. A bit misleading, but easy to test and see for yourself.

As stated, the catch is the "incosistency" which can be demonstrated with another example ( `async/await` only for brevity of listing):

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose'),
      Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.set('debug',true);

const uri = 'mongodb://localhost/test',
      options = { useMongoClient: true };

const songSchema = new Schema({
  _id: Number,
  name: String
});

const Song = mongoose.model('Song', songSchema);

function log(data) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2))
}

let docs = [
  { _id: 1, name: "something" },
  { _id: 2, name: "something else" },
  { _id: 2, name: "something else entirely" },
  { _id: 3, name: "another thing" },
  { _id: 4, name: "different thing" },
  //{ _id: 4, name: "different thing again" }
];

(async function() {

  try {
    const conn = await mongoose.connect(uri,options);

    await Song.remove();

    try {
      let results = await Song.insertMany(docs,{ ordered: false });
      console.log('what? no result!');
      log(results);   // not going to get here
    } catch(e) {
      // Log something for the sake of it
      console.log('Has write Errors:');

      // Check to see if something else other than a duplicate key, then throw
      // Branching because MongoError is not consistent
      if (e.hasOwnProperty('writeErrors')) {
        log(e.writeErrors);
        if(e.writeErrors.some( error => error.code !== 11000 ))
          throw e;
      } else if (e.code !== 11000) {
        throw e;
      } else {
        log(e);
      }

    }

    let songs = await Song.find();
    log(songs);

  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
  } finally {
    mongoose.disconnect();
  }


})()
```

All much the same thing, but pay attention to how the error logs here:

```
Has write Errors:
{
  "code": 11000,
  "index": 2,
  "errmsg": "E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.songs index: _id_ dup key: { : 2 }",
  "op": {
    "__v": 0,
    "_id": 2,
    "name": "something else entirely"
  }
}
```

Note that there is no "success" information, even though we get the same continuation of the listing by doing the subsequent `.find()` and getting the output. This is because the implementation only acts on the "thrown error" in rejection and never passes through the actual `result` part. So even though we asked for `ordered: false`, we don't get the information about what was completed unless we wrap the callback and implement the logic ourselves, as is shown in the initial listings.

The other important "inconsistency" happens when there is "more than one error". So uncommenting the additional value for `_id: 4` gives us:

```
Has write Errors:
[
  {
    "code": 11000,
    "index": 2,
    "errmsg": "E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.songs index: _id_ dup key: { : 2 }",
    "op": {
      "__v": 0,
      "_id": 2,
      "name": "something else entirely"
    }
  },
  {
    "code": 11000,
    "index": 5,
    "errmsg": "E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.songs index: _id_ dup key: { : 4 }",
    "op": {
      "__v": 0,
      "_id": 4,
      "name": "different thing again"
    }
  }
]
```

Here you can see the code "branched" on the presence of `e.writeErrors`, which does not exist when there is **one** error. By contrast the earlier `response` object has both the `hasWriteErrors()` and `getWriteErrors()` methods, regardless of any error being present at all. So that is the more consistent interface and the reason why you should use it instead of inspecting the `err` response alone.

---

## MongoDB 3.x Driver Fixes

This behavior is actually fixed in the upcoming 3.x release of the driver which is meant to coincide with the MongoDB 3.6 server release. The behavior changes in that the `err` response is more akin to the standard `result`, but of course classed as a `BulkWriteError` response instead of `MongoError` which it presently is.

Until that is released ( and of course until that dependency and changes are propagated to the "mongoose" implementation ), then the recommended course of action is to be aware that the useful information is in the `result` and **not** the `err`. In fact your code probably should look for `hasErrors()` in the `result` and then fallback to check `err` as well, in order to cater for the change to be implemented in the driver.

> **Authors Note:** Much of this content and related reading is actually already answered here on [Function insertMany() unordered: proper way to get both the errors and the result?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46841840/2313887) and [MongoDB Node.js native driver silently swallows `bulkWrite` exception](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46700933/2313887). But repeating and elaborating here until it finally sinks in to people that this is the way you handle exceptions in the current driver implementation. And it does actually work, when you look in the correct place and write your code to handle it accordingly.

Comment: Long post, I read it, thanks to point out this but what's the answer besides to avoid insertMany?

Comment: @JennyMok If that's all you understood then you really should take the time to read through properly, run the examples and understand what is actually happening. We certainly don't "avoid" at all as this is showing you "in detail" how you **do it correctly**. Short answer is "you did it wrong". Long answer is "do this and understand why you got errors, and how you avoid them".

Comment: so what should I do? u throw an open question without really giving me the direction. I can do loop and use findOneAndUpdate but is that really the way to do it? I have no problem to make the thing just work but I'm trying to find best solution.

Comment: @JennyMok Stop there and calm down. There is a "lot" of explanation here and there are also practical examples to run and actually "understand it". Stack Overflow is not a "write my code for me" service. What you "have been given" is a very useful resource for you to understand what you did wrong and how to implement it correctly. It works both ways here. You are actually expected to apply yourself, and I have indeed demonstrated "avoiding duplicate errors" just as was asked in the question. Take a breath and sit down and take the time to comprehend something new.

Comment: @JennyMok If you "tried" it would take you a lot more than 5 minutes to actually run the examples and understand them. Don't "cherry pick"!. This is a concept you don't understand and some nice person has taken the time to write out the necessary lecture notes and exercises for you. Sit down and work it out. The code I have given you demonstrates what to do. Run it! Learn it! "Then" try to apply to your only usage. But only when you understand it. "Take a breath" means I really don't need to receive comment notifications from you every two minutes.

Comment: I don't get it mate, that's a fact. I know the consistency problem, thank you for pointing that out, but who cares, I just need the correct implementation.

Comment: @JennyMok Run the code. Works exactly as the output shown in the answer proves it does. This is how it's done, so it's time you actually sat down an "got it" because it's not like there is a different answer.

Comment: which code are you talking about? ur code is basically reproduce the error, I don't want any of that, I need a solution.

Comment: @JennyMok There is no error in the code I have listed, as the "output" I show comes from me actually running the provided. Stop trying to run your own code and simply copy and paste the provided code until you actually understand it. Stop commenting. It's going to take you time to understand.

Comment: The syntax changed, it works like this right now

```
await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      Song.collection.insertMany(docs, { ordered: false }, (err) => {
        if (err && err.writeErrors.length) {
          // Check to see if something else other than a duplicate key, and throw

          if (err.writeErrors.some((err2) => {
            return err2.code !== 11000;
          })) {
            reject(err);
          }
        }

        resolve();
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried a combination of the following options when calling the `insertMany()` Mongoose method, but *none* of these worked for me:

```js
{ ordered: false, silent: true, keepGoing: true, continueOnError: 1, safe: true }
```

I think that's because those only work for ignoring unique `_id` fields--not for *other* fields that are specified to be `unique: true` in the model's schema.

In the end, I just looped over my new documents array, and used the `Model.exists()` method to check first if the field value already exists in a document in the collection, and then pushed the object literal into an array if it didn't.

Assuming your schema looks something like this:

```js
field: {
    type: String,
    require: true,
    unique: true
}
```

I just looped over an array of object literals that were structured like my schema, and pushed into another array if the field hasn't been used yet:

```js
const docs = [
    { field: "I'm unique!" },
    { field: "I'm unique, too!" },
    { field: "I'm unique!" } // <-- dupe
];

const newDocs = [];
for (let i = 0; i < docs.length; i++) {
    let fieldVal = docs[i].field;

    // check if that unique field already exists in the collection
    await Model.exists({ field: fieldVal }).then((exists) => {
        if (exists) {
            console.warn(`Field '${fieldVal}' already exists.`);
        } else {
            newDocs.push(docs[i]);
        }
    });
}
```

Now take that final array of new documents to insert and pass it to the `Model.insertMany()` method:

```js
const options = {
    ordered: false,
    silent: true,
    keepGoing: true,
    continueOnError: 1,
    safe: true
};

const final = await Model.insertMany(newDocs, options)
    .then((docs) => {
        return docs;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err.message);
        return [];
    });

console.log(`Inserted ${final.length} documents`);
```

The downside is that it takes **a lot** longer to loop over each object literal and check the field values before inserting. I'm sure there's a better way to do this, but this is what worked for me since I only had a few hundred documents to insert.