# Nodejs mongodb driver hangs on client close

Tags: node.js, mongodb, database-connection

I have the following code, and can't understand why my process hangs on the line that tries to close the connection to mongodb, here is my code:

```
async function save(clientCredentials, newFieldsToUpdate){

    const url = `mongodb://${clientCredentials.username}:${clientCredentials.password}@my.server.ip:22222/${clientCredentials.database}`

    const client = await MongoClient.connect(url, {useNewUrlParser:true, useUnifiedTopology: true})
        .catch(err => { console.log(err); });

    const db = client.db(clientName);

    const collection = await db.collection("products");

    let execute = false;

    const updateOps = [];

    for(let objectIdentifier in newFieldsToUpdate){

        let updateOperation = {};
        updateOperation['$set'] = newFieldsToUpdate[objectIdentifier];

        let id = mongodb.ObjectID(objectIdentifier);
        execute = true;
        updateOps.push({ updateOne: { filter: {_id: id}, update: {$set: newFieldsToUpdate[objectIdentifier]}, upsert:true } })

    }

    if(execute){

        try {
           console.log('executing');  // I see this line
           let report = await collection.bulkWrite(updateOps);
           console.log('executed');   // I see this line
           await client.close();
           console.log('closed conn');  // I don't see this line! why? it's weird
           return report;
        } catch(ex){
            console.error(ex);
        }       
    } else {
        console.log('not executing');
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for any help!

EDIT: The bulk operation is of about 200 documents only, if I try with a single document it works, this is weird. Mongodb driver for node version 3.3.2

EDIT2: I notice that using the parameter poolSize:1 on the mongo connect it closes the connection with success, but using the default poolSize of 5 it doesnt close, any suggestions why this might be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are using latest version of `mongodb` driver (delete node_modules just to be sure) as older version has a bug in which `bulkWrite` method fails silently because of some bug mentioned here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/46700933/1021796

Before trying to close the connection, you shou also check if it is connected or not. so code will be

```
if (client.isConnected) {
  await client.close();
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: The client is connected, I tested now using piece of code. I am using mongodb version 3.3.2 can that be the cause? Thanks.

Comment: the version looks ok. can you share the code which you tested as it looks like issue with `batchWrite` I also tested it with normal `find` function and it closes the connection properly?

Comment: the code I am testing is in the question itself, what you mean? thanks

Comment: I thought you are talking about a happy scenario test. Can you also try to replace `bulkWrite` with let's say a simple `find` and see the issue is still there?

Comment: I have added an alternative code in my answer, can you try to do that as well? Looks like it is a problem if bulkWrite swallowing the exception.

Comment: I believe its not swallowing any exception because I console logged the result of the bulk write and it says the following: {"ok":1,"writeErrors":[],"writeConcernErrors":[],"insertedIds":[],"nInserted":0,"nUpserted":0,"nMatched":191,"nModified":191,"nRemoved":0,"upserted":[],"lastOp":{"ts":"6779506499782705343","t":1}}

Comment: using find method instead of bulkWrite closes the connection with success. The problem is on the bulkWrite. I tried however a bulkWrite with a single document and works fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205585/discussion-between-ashish-modi-and-tiagom).

Comment: After installing the latest 3.4.1 mongodb driver it started working, thank you!